# Help understanding the usage of 「で」 in this clause

Tags: grammar, meaning

I get the gist of this answer, but I fear I might be misunderstanding the very last part of the second sentence:

> 「今週末」と同じ意味なのは「今度の週末」じゃなくて「今週の週末」かな。
>
> 今度の週末は次の週末と同じ意味で、日曜日では「今度の週末」は「来週末」**のことで「今週末」「今週の週末」とは**違う日を指す。

My understanding is this:

> "This weekend" doesn't have the same meaning as "this time's weekend" but instead "this week's weekend".
>
> 'This time's weekend' is the same as 'next weekend', and on Sunday, [the idea of] "this time's weekend" is the same as "next week's weekend", so it is different from "this weekend" and "this week's weekend" because they refer to different days.

Comment: で is here the continuative of だ. incidentally i think 今度 is probably best to translate in this context as "next".

Comment: The word 週末 is not clear in Japan, so NHK recommends to say in its broadcasting like 今週の土曜, 今週の金曜, 来週の日曜, etc. in stead of 今週末 or 来週末https://www.nhk.or.jp/bunken/summary/kotoba/gimon/133.html

Comment: 今度 is tricky: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CxGC-8wXUAAci0S.jpg:large

Comment: btw you should clarify if you really want to know just about で or the whole weekend thing.

Comment: @mackygoo - Thank you for that - I understand the answer more now.

Comment: @A.Ellett
Okay - so it's just an example of the て-form after nouns. I have read about it extensively with verbs and adjectives from a variety of sources, but oddly enough, nouns were not covered in any of them.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still a bit confused, with と this time.

日曜日では「今度の週末」は「来週末」のことで「今週末」「今週の週末」とは違う日を指す。

Would the translation of that part be more like:

"On Sunday, 「今度の週末」means 「来週末」so they mean different days from「今週末」and「今週の週末」"

Or:

"On Sunday, 「今度の週末」means 「来週末」and「今週末」and「今週の週末」also refer to different days."

I'm thinking it's the former, because the second translation would probably need 「も」.

(Sorry, my knowledge of basic Japanese is still patchy)

Also, you guys have helped me understand the weekend thing too (as well as 「今度」), so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> 今度の週末は次の週末と同じ意味**で**、日曜日では「今度の週末」は「来週末」のこと**で**「今週末」「今週の週末」とは違う日を指す。

The two で's are both the てform (or the continuative form/連用形) of the copula (or the assertive auxiliary) 「だ」.  The で's here basically mean "... is ~~, and". So this sentence can be split into three clauses like this:

> 1. 今度の週末は次の週末と同じ意味だ。
> 2. そして、 日曜日では「今度の週末」は「来週末」のことだ。
> 3. そして、(日曜日では「今度の週末」は)「今週末」「今週の週末」とは違う日を指す。

which would respectively translate to:

> 1. 今度の週末(this/next/coming weekend) has the same meaning as 次の週末(next weekend).
> 2. And, on Sunday, 今度の週末(this/next/coming weekend) refers to 来週末(end of next week).
> 3. And, (on Sunday, 今度の週末(this/next/coming weekend)) refers to a different day from 今週末(end of this week) or 今週の週末(weekend of this week).

(#2 and #3 share the same subject.)

---

「～～と(は)違う」 means "to be different from ~~". So #3 literally means:

> 「今度の週末」は、（「今週末」「今週の週末」とは違う）日を指す。
>   今度の週末 refers to a day (which is different from 今週末 or 今週の週末).

「今週末」「今週の週末」とは違う is a relative clause modifying the noun 日.

---

By the way, by the first sentence they're saying...

> 「今週末」と同じ意味なのは「今度の週末」じゃなくて「今週の週末」かな。
>   今週末(end of this week) has the same meaning as 今週の週末(weekend of this week), rather than 今度の週末(this/next/coming weekend), I think.

(They're trying to say 今週末 is [今週]{this week}+[末]{end}, not [今]{this}+[週末]{weekend}.)

Answer (score 0):

[translation](/questions/tagged/translation)[grammar](/questions/tagged/grammar)[syntax](/questions/tagged/syntax)[word-choice](/questions/tagged/word-choice)[meaning](/questions/tagged/meaning)

> 「今週末」と同じ意味なのは「今度の週末」じゃなくて「今週の週末」かな。
>
> 今度の週末は次の週末と同じ意味で、日曜日では「今度の週末」は「来週末」のこと**で**「今週末」「今週の週末」とは違う日を指す。
>
> ・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・
> The one that means the same with「this coming weekends」今週末 would be 「this week's weekend」今週の週末 rather than 「next time's weekend」今度の週末.
>
> 「next time's weekend」今度の週末 and 「next week's weekend」次の週末　means the same; and in case today is Sunday, 「next time's weekend」今度の週末 skips to (the weekend days of )「next week」来週末; and therefore, it is pointing to a different day from what 「this coming weekend」今週末 and 「this week's weekened」今週の週末 refer to.

で in bold, can be read as 「だから」or 「であるから」
To rewrite in easier-to-read sentences,
今度の週末は次の週末と同じ意味です。
もし今日が日曜日だと「今度の週末」は「来週末」のこと**だから**「今週末」「今週の週末」とは違う日を指す。
or
もし今日が日曜日だと「今度の週末」は「来週末」のこと**であるから**「今週末」「今週の週末」とは違う日を指します。